# How can I access services in Blazor Web Assembly (Client) or handle Dependency Injection from utility classes?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-client-side

In .razor files I can use something like "@inject HttpClient Http".

However, I have moved some functionality that is used by multiple components off into a static utility class. This is implemented in C# code.
How can I access HttpClient from these?
Likewise, how could I access something like Console.WriteLine from these?

Thanks

Comment: "... into a __static__ utility class" - static doesn't play nice with DI. Look at the WeatherForecastService and how it is registered in Startup. In such a service you can use constructor injection.

Comment: For static classes pass in whatever you need to use in the Method parameters. example. `MyStaticUtility.Foo(httpClient, myOtherParameter)`

Comment: Yes, I have been using this approach as a work-around but hoped there was a better way.